# gnuplot hypertext is not working

Tags: gnuplot

I have the below gnuplot script, I'm trying to display the third column when the mouse hover over a point of the plot.

```
set title "Cloud"
set xlabel "Date"
set ylabel "Number"
filename ='data.dat'
stats filename using 4 nooutput

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'
set format x '%Y'


rand_x(x) = x + 60*60*24*7 * (rand(0) - 0.5)
rand_y(y) = y + (rand(0) - 0.5)
set xrange [ "1995-01-19":"2013-12-12" ]
plot for [i=0:int(STATS_max)-1] filename \
using (rand_x(timecolumn(1))):(i < $4 ? rand_y($2) : 1/0):3 pointtype 7 linecolor  palette notitle
u 0:1:2 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb "#ffee99"
```

And the data file looks like below:

```
1999-01-19  21  0   1
2009-07-01  0   1   1
2008-08-20  2   1   1
2008-12-18  1   1   1
2004-05-12  4   1   1
2009-07-29  2   1   1
2008-08-07  0   1   1
2006-03-08  1   1   1
2004-08-31  9   1   1
2001-03-27  12  1   1
2009-08-19  0   1   1
2010-07-14  2   1   1
2009-06-24  0   1   1
2009-11-11  0   1   1
2010-10-13  0   1   1
2012-02-22  0   1   1
2011-05-11  0   1   1
2011-03-03  0   1   1
2011-09-21  0   1   1
2011-12-20  0   1   1
2011-10-05  0   1   1
2012-05-03  0   1   1
2011-10-05  0   2   1
2013-01-09  0   2   1
2011-06-03  0   2   1
```

So can you please tell me what's wrong with my script?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a remark for the readers: `hypertext` works only with the 4.7 development version.

To your problem: For plotting the labels, you must also use the same x and y columns 1 and 2 (you use 0 and 1). And you need the third column for the labels and a fourth one for the `ps var`. So your plot part for the labels is:

```
plot for [i=0:int(STATS_max)-1] filename \
using (rand_x(timecolumn(1))):(i < $4 ? rand_y($2) : 1/0):3 pointtype 7 linecolor  palette notitle,\
'' u 1:2:3:3 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb "#ffee99"
```

Comment: Thx Christoph, but how can I download gnuplot 4.7? I can't find the download link in their website!

Comment: I thought you were using the dev version. Or how did you know about the `hypertext` feature? For Windows, see http://www.gnuplot.info/development/binaries/, but the last version there is as of 2013-08-01. For Linux you must compile it yourself.

Comment: I know hypertext feature from Google after I tried to find a solution for the mouse hover. BTW, I downloaded 4.7 version, and I didn't work. Where do I have to see the label along with the column content?

Comment: I updated the answer to hold the complete plot command, you were also  missing a comma and a backslash before the label-part. And the hypertext works only for some terminals (wxt, qt, svg, canvas, win). Using the version 2013-08-01 gives me http://i.stack.imgur.com/9zmlB.png, see the label in the center, the mouse pointer was hidden when taking the screenshot.

Comment: Thx @Christoph, It works! You are always helping me in this project :)

Comment: you see that I'm plotting the points with random function, and the labels are not place directly on the points already plotted. How can I manage that?

Comment: That seems to be fix. The tooltip is displayed 1 character width to the right and 1/2 character height below the anchor point.

Comment: I modified the script this way:
[plot for [i=0:int(STATS_max)-1] filename \
using (rand_x(timecolumn(1))):(i < $4 ? rand_y($2) : 1/0):3:3 with labels hypertext point pt 7 linecolor  palette notitle
]
but why the points are not colored?

Comment: It works with the dev version 2013-11-14, I don't know when it was fixed/changed.